# How to check if the autocomplete suggestion is a POI?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I use google map autocomplete, I need to check if the value is a POI (point of interest)

Can somebody suggest a simple method?

Example :
If user type and submit "Hartford, CT" OR "XL Center, Trumbull Street, Hartford, CT", I need to differentiate first one is a city and another one is a POI. After I need to send a different ajax call for both value.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check the user's current location. Then, the location that the autocomplete gives you is inverse of the distance from that user's current location. So, if its near its a POI while if it's far its not much of a POI. Then, if you want just a single place choose the one that gets the maximum value.

Comment: I am really sorry if you misunderstood my question. I'll expline to you with some example. If user type "Hartford, CT" OR "XL Center, Trumbull Street, Hartford, CT", I need to differentiate first one is a city and another one is a POI.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the place_changed event of the `autocomplete` , the getPlace()-method of the autocomplete will return the [**PlaceResult**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#PlaceResult) which contains details for the place, e.g. the `types` .

But your definition of a POI is different from the definition of the API's , for these places it returns e.g.:

- Hartford, CT : `["locality","political"]`
- XL Center, Trumbull Street, Hartford, CT : `["health","establishment"]`

The available types are listed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

You'll need to decide  whether this place is a POI(in your definition) or not  by the returned types, e.g. when the types contain `"political"` it would'nt be a POI in your definition

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle, We are using your above method for getting POI. 
But I am not sure this method are accurate. For Eg:   

Hartford, CT : ["locality","political"]  
XL Center, Trumbull Street, Hartford, CT : ["health","establishment"]  
Toyota center, Polk Street, Houston, TX : [ "locality", "political" ]  
But my client are considering "XL Center and Toyota center" are POI's.
So I am looking any other method like "featureType", But I don't know how to use this method and is it useful for my requirement.

Comment: the type for the search for Toyota Center is correct. When you inspect the result you'll see that the returned result is for Houston, TX (seems as if there is no place found for the query )